# How can I do safe delete using Realm

Tags: swift, realm

Some times app crashes saying object has been deleted.

Please let me know how can I delete with catch exception.

Comment: please provide some detail error message or console output.

Answer (score 2):

you have to check for the object if it is invalidated or not

```
if !myObject.isInvalidated {
    //the object exists and it is safe to handle it
}
```

Comment: How can check on an object which is not retrieved yet.

Comment: what do you mean by not retrieved? can you provide an example?!