# How can I clear in-memory realm data in right time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

How can I clear in-memory realm data in right time? I want to use a in-memory realm for a view controller's data source, but I need to clear it when the view controller released. How can I do it and what is the right time?? I have tried this for several times, but I have not got a right place to clear data for in-memory realm, until it is cleared when across launches.

Comment: Didn’t you just ask this at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46291463/how-can-i-do-safe-delete-using-realm?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide the actual code you tried and explain how it didn't do what you were expecting it to do and don't just write _"I have tried this for several times"_ without showing what is it you actually tried.

Answer (score 0):

In-memory Realm data is cleared when the Realm instance is deallocated. For example, the view controller holds the Realm instance, (and anyone has any strong reference to the Realm instance) in-memory Realm data will be cleared if the view controller released.